# Spring AOP not being applied when I split the method

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

This is my first post on stackoverflow... 
Well here it goes. 
I have a custom spring AOP annotation which works fine for this method

```
@testInterceptor
public MyObjList getMyObjList( List qlist,Context cntxt){
//some processing
List<MyObj> myObjList= getMyObjs(qlist,cntxt);
//Some more processing
return myObjList;
}


public List<MyObj> getMyObjs( List qlist,Context cntxt){ 
List<MyObj> myObjList= new ArrayList<MyObj>(); 
//Some more processing 
return myObjList; 
}
```

I realized that this annotation should actually be at the  getMyObjs() method. 
So I moved the annotation to the getMyObjs() but for some reason now the aspect is not being applied. 
I have no idea why.

```
@testInterceptor
public List<MyObj> getMyObjs( List qlist,Context cntxt){ 
List<MyObj> myObjList= new ArrayList<MyObj>(); 
//Some more processing 
return myObjList; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to how Spring uses AOP, in order for `@testInterceptor` to work on `getMyObjs`, that method needs to be called from outside the class. Calling it from `getMyObjList` will not get the interceptor involved.

Check out [this](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2011/10/spring-pitfalls-proxying.html) blog post for more details.

To clarify what I above with an example:

Let's say you have another class

```
class Foo {

   @Autowired
   private MyObjList myObjList; 

   //this will invode the interceptor
   public void willWork() {
     myObjList.getMyObjs();
   }

   public void willNotWork() {
     myObjList.getMyObjList(); //will not invoke interceptor since `getMyObjs` is being invoked from inside the class that it's defined
   }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the link.I read it... but didnt quite understand it :( Infact, originally whatever was done in the getmyobjs() was part of the original method. I just separated the logic into another method.

Comment: @geonad, What do you mean when you say "that method needs to be called from outside the class" ? Both the methods are part of the same class.

Comment: @MonaD I added an example to my answer

Comment: Thanks.. Got what you are saying.. correct me if my understanding is wrong...basically the original method is being called by another class  so spring has a proxy for it and so applies the aspect. But for the other method call, its just a local call from within the same class.